# Cookie Cake Combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I am making a cookie cake with 4 slices. I have 20 types of sprinkles, and can use none, one, two or three types on each slice. How many combinations can I make?

Importantly, all cakes that can be created by rotating another combination shall not count (except for one, of course).

Calculating the number of combinations in a single quadrant is quite simple: 20C3 + 20C2 + 20 + 1 However, I can't seem to progress any further, despite consulting my textbook as well as the internet.

Comment: [You asked this exact question before.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4180539/409) Re-posting a question is not the appropriate way to draw more attention to it; rather, you should edit the original to make clarifications or improve quality. (Note that an edit will "bump" a question to the top of the Unanswered queue, so you get the benefits of a re-post without cluttering the site with duplicates. Note also, though, that non-substantive edits *just* to bump a question are discouraged.)

Comment: @Blue This brings up a sensitive issue.  My understanding of the rules, re re-posting a question, **agrees** with your comment.  However, since the OP has clearly shown work, both this question and the original question are not (in my opinion) low quality.  As a practical matter, once 24 hours have passed, with no acceptable answer received, how long should the OP wait until re-posting?  Of course, my question assumes that you agree with my characterization of both this question and the original question as being of reasonably high quality.

Comment: To the OP: given that there is a difference of opinion about whether your re-posted question should receive an answer, the best that I can do is offer Hint/Comments:  If the number of different toppings combinations for one slice is $(k)$, and if the slices are **deemed distinguishable** from each other, the overall number of different ways of having topping combinations re all 4 slices is $(k^4).$  If the slices are **deemed indistinguishable**, then the problem becomes much tougher: ...see next comment

Comment: There may be an elegant simplification to the problem of indistinguishable slices, that I am not aware of.  Anyway suppose that the slices are indistinguishable, and that there are only 3 possible toppings for each slice.  Then, the answer of $\frac{3^4}{4!}$ is wrong, because not every distribution will have been counted $(4!)$ times.  For example, if the toppings are A,B, and C, then the distribution AABC would have only been counted $(12)$ times, while the distribution AAAB would only have been counted $(4)$ times.

Comment: @user2661923: *"how long should the OP wait until re-posting?"* My understanding is that the user shouldn't re-post "ever" (although I'm not *actually* that absolutist about things). There is nothing stopping the user from editing the original to add more context or thoughts, to earn the "edit bump". Re-posting just contributes to site clutter. Deleting-and-reposting can be problematic: Someone seeing the original, crafting a *excellent* answer off-site, and returning to find that original *gone* might not realize the asker had re-posted. A rarity, sure, but avoidable by editing. So do *that*.

Comment: @Blue My reading of the original question is that it did not need editing, just as (in my opinion) this one doesn't need editing.  In both cases, the OP showed significant work.  Therefore, there is no call to edit the original question to improve its quality; the question needed no improvement (at least in my opinion).

Comment: @user2661923: Note [this Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32514/409) asking if it's okay to re-post a question after a *month*. The answer, from a moderator, is "No. [...]". ... Eventually, OP will have enough reputation to offer bounties; until then, an edit-bump is "the" way to attract eyeballs. It's not unreasonable to ask an asker to provide more context to even a perfectly-written question, if only to write "I've spent another full day pondering this, and I'm *still* not making progress". (That said, I'd tend to expect a day of *active* pondering to bear more fruit.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach. Granted, it is a bit of "overkill". This assumes that the slices are deemed indistinguishable, which I believe is the intention. I also assume that the location of the slice within the (presumably) circular cookie is maintained upon "rotation".

Each slice can be given one of
$$
_{20}C_3 + {}_{20}C_2 + 20 + 1 = 1351
$$
combinations of sprinkles. With that, we are looking for the total number of $k$-ary [necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)#Number_of_necklaces) of length $4$ with $k=1351$. As the formula on the linked page states, we have
$$
N_k(4) = \frac 14 \sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d) k^{4/d} 
\\ = \frac 14[1 \cdot k^4 + 1 \cdot k^2 + 2 \cdot k^1] = \frac{k^4 + k^2 + 2k}{4} \approx 8.33 \times 10^{11}
$$

---

So as not to rely on a complicated formula, here is a justification of the fact that there are $(k^4 + k^2 + 2k)/4$ $k$-ary necklaces of length $4$.

We apply [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) (which is arguably yet another complicated formula), noting that we are counting the distinct orbits within the set of "oriented necklaces" under the action of the cyclic group of order $4$. For each $g \in C_4 = \{1,r,r^2,r^3\}$ (where $r$ corresponds to a $90^\circ$ rotation), we compute $|X^g|$.

With $g = 1$, it is clear that $|X^g| = k^4$.

For $g = r^2$, we note that a necklace is fixed by $g$ if and only if each pair of diagonally opposite beads is identical. Thus, we have $|X^{r^2}| = k^2$.

For $g = r$, a necklace is fixed if and only if all beads are identical. Thus, we have $|X^r| = k$. By a similar consideration, conclude that $|X^{r^3}| = k$.

With that, Burnside's lemma leads us to conclude that
$$
|X/G| = \frac 1{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} |X^g| = \frac 14 \left[k^4 + k^2 + 2 \cdot k\right],
$$
as indicated by the formula.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  Consider my comments, which followed the posted question, on the distinguishable and indistinguishable versions of the prob.  Intuitively, it seems that the only reason that $\frac{k^4}{4!}$ is wrong is because sometimes, the same topping will repeat among two or more slices.  As $k$ grows large, I would expect this possibility to **relatively** diminish.  This means that my intuition suggests that as $k$ grows very large, the right answer tends towards $\frac{k^4}{4!}.$  Given your 189k rep and that you are quoting a theorem, I must be wrong; I'm just not seeing why.

Comment: @user2661923 I'm pretty sure. *None* of the sprinkle distributions will be counted $4!$ times: because we only consider distributions to be the same if you can obtain one from the other by *rotation* (rather than arbitrary slice rearrangement), a single distribution will be counted at most $4$ times.

Comment: Nice response.  You are interpreting the problem in (perhaps) its most natural way; where overall rotations of the cake are deemed the same.  So my estimate of $\frac{k^4}{4!}$ **unnaturally** assumes that after the toppings are placed on each of the 4 slices, the slices are placed on separate plates, and then the plates are placed in **random** order.  So, the problem actually permits not two, but three interpretations.

Comment: @user2661923 Your interpretation hadn't occurred to me, but it makes sense. There is a distinct possibility that "rotating" is the result of a mistranslation so that the problem is concerned with arbitrary permutations after all.